# Why does Windows PowerShell font size not reflect reality?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

On Windows 7 if I set my PowerShell window to Consolas 14, it looks very different to Microsoft Word 2010 Consolas 14. See picture. Which is right, and why do they look different?

[image: Fixed image - Word at 100% ZOOM]

Comment: What is the zoom level in word?

Comment: Good point, I've resubmitted the image with Word 2010 at 100% zoom.